# Animation between two activities

Tags: java, android

I have a login activity, and in this activity I check if the user are already connected by checking a column value in the SQLite database.

My problem is when the user are already connected so I have to finish this activity and start another one, and that makes a bad animation, because the login activity opens and and then closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach is:

```
Login_activity --> (login)--> Main_activity
```

My suggestion is:

```
Main_activity --> Check login --> if not logged in, start Login_activity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty activity that only looks at the DB and launches the appropriate activity.

Assuming that you have 2 activities right now (Login and Main), the idea is that you'd have 3 activities:

1. Root
2. Login
3. Main

In `Root`'s `onCreate()` you'd check if the user is already logged in. If *yes*, then launch `Main`. Otherwise launch `Login`. You can keep the current logic `Login` -> `Main`.

Nguyen's answer keeps you to your 2 activities, but then the logic in the `Main` activity is a bit more complicated.

Comment: I want when the app start check first if the user is already connected or not if he is, so the app will start directly the other activity, without starting the login activity